# Problem loading php page via shadowbox

Tags: php, jquery, thickbox, colorbox, shadowbox

Hy I have a html page in witch I want to open a php page via shadowbox, the problem is in IE 6/7/8 the page is loading but it is not displaing, it works perfectly in FF 
this is the hole page, the problem occures when you click on contact@termo-gaz-instal.ro at the bottom of the page. I have tried using colorbox and thickbox

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet", href="style.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet", href="shadowbox-3.0.3/shadowbox.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet", href="colorbox/example1/colorbox.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="colorbox/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/moving-boxes.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="shadowbox-3.0.3/shadowbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Shadowbox.init();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".example7").colorbox({width:"80%", height:"80%", iframe:true});
 });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wraper">
<div id="logo">
  <img class="poza" src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" width="311" height="106">
  <h1>TERMO GAZ INSTAL</h1>

</div><!--logo -->
<div id="spacer"></div>
<div id="container">

<div id="slider">    

            <img class="scrollButtons left" src="images/leftarrow.png">

   <div style="overflow: hidden;" class="scroll">

    <div class="scrollContainer">

                 <div class="panel" id="panel_1">
      <div class="inside">
       <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="picture" />
       <h2>News Heading</h2>
       <p>A very shot exerpt goes here... <a href="http://flickr.com/photos/justbcuz/112479862/">more link</a></p>
      </div>
     </div>

                 <div class="panel" id="panel_2">
      <div class="inside">
       <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="picture" />
       <h2>News Heading</h2>
       <p>A very shot exerpt goes here... <a href="http://flickr.com/photos/joshuacraig/2698975899/">more link</a></p>
      </div>
     </div>

                 <div class="panel" id="panel_3">
      <div class="inside">

                            <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="picture" />
       <h2>News Heading</h2>
       <p>A very shot exerpt goes here... <a href="http://flickr.com/photos/ruudvanleeuwen/468309897/">more link</a></p>
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="panel" id="panel_4">
      <div class="inside">
       <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="picture" />
       <h2>News Heading</h2>
       <p>A very shot exerpt goes here... <a href="http://flickr.com/photos/emikohime/294092478/">more link</a></p>
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="panel" id="panel_5">
      <div class="inside">
       <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="picture" />
       <h2>News Heading</h2>
       <p>A very shot exerpt goes here... <a href="http://flickr.com/photos/fensterbme/499006584/">more link</a></p>
      </div>
     </div>

                </div>

    <div id="left-shadow"></div>
    <div id="right-shadow"></div>

            </div>

   <img class="scrollButtons right" src="images/rightarrow.png">

        </div>


</div><!--container -->
<div id="spacer"></div>
<div id="important_txt">
<span class="important_txt">Sistemele</span> de instalatii ultraperformante ce sunt sustinute de un <span class="important_txt">design</span> bine gandit si de un <span class="important_txt">management</span> performant.<br> 
Instalatiile de <span class="important_txt">gaz, apa si canalizare</span> sunt o parte <span class="important_txt">importanta</span> a vietii noastre indiferent de circumstantele in care ne aflam. <span class="important_txt">Executia</span> acestor lucrari este <span class="important_txt">importanta</span> deoarece de ea depinde <span class="important_txt">siguranta</span> si <span class="important_txt">bunastarea</span> noastra.

</div><!--important -->

  <div id="imag">
  <div class="stg">

  <img class="imag" src="images/imag_06.png" width="222" height="222" alt="apa">
  <div id="txt">
  <span class="stg_s">INSTALATII DE APA<br> CALDA SI RECE</span><br>

  <span class="stg_j">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultricies nulla massa. Suspendisse venenatis euismod adipiscing. Donec urna mauris, hendrerit.<a href="#read" rel="shadowbox"> <span style="color:#FFF; font-size:11px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration:underline;">Mai mult</span></a> </span>


<div id="read" style="display:none;">
        <div id="content" style="padding:20px;color:white;">
            <p>1This content was taken from a hidden div in this page!</p>
        </div>
    </div> 



  </div><!--txt -->
  </div><!--stg -->


  <div class="stg1">
  <img class="imag" src="images/imag_08.png" width="222" height="222" alt="gaz">
  <div id="txt">
  <span class="stg_s">INSTALATII DE GAZ</span><br><br>

  <span class="stg_j1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultricies nulla massa. Suspendisse venenatis euismod adipiscing. Donec urna mauris, hendrerit.<a href="#read2" rel="shadowbox"><span style="color:#FFF; font-size:11px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration:underline;">Mai mult</span></a> </span>

 <div id="read2" style="display:none;">
        <div id="content" style="padding:20px;color:white;">
            <p>12This content was taken from a hidden div in this page!</p>
        </div>
    </div> 

  </div><!--txt -->
  </div><!--stg1 -->


 <div class="stg1">
  <img class="imag" src="images/imag_10.png" width="222" height="222" alt="gaz">
  <div id="txt">
  <span class="stg_s">INSTALATII DE DEJECTIE</span><br><br>

  <span class="stg_j1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultricies nulla massa. Suspendisse venenatis euismod adipiscing. Donec urna mauris, hendrerit. <a href="#read3" rel="shadowbox"><span style="color:#FFF; font-size:11px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration:underline;">Mai mult</span></a></span>

  <div id="read3" style="display:none;">
        <div id="content" style="padding:20px;color:white;">
            <p>123This content was taken from a hidden div in this page!</p>
        </div>
    </div> 

  </div><!--txt -->
  </div><!--stg -->
 <div id="clear"></div>



  </div><!--imag -->






</div><!--wraper --><br><br>


<div id="footer">
<div id="wraper">

<div id="footer_stg">
<p class="tel_cont">TELEFON DE CONTACT</p>
<img class="bula" src="images/bula.png" width="76" height="75" alt="Text Bubble"><br>
<span class="telefon">+40 021<span class="telefon1"> 201 35 55</span></span>

</div><!--footer_stg -->

<div id="footer_dr">

<a rel="shadowbox" href="http://www.google.com" ><p class="contact">CONTACT</p></a>
<a href="http://minavet.ro/apasigaz/contact.php" rel="shadowbox" ><p class="contact1">contact@termo-gaz-instal.ro</p></a>

</div><!--footer_dr -->
<div id="clear"></div>
<br>
<div id="spacer1"></div>
<p style="font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18px; color:#545454; float:left;">termo-gaz-instal.ro &copy; toate drepturile rezervate</p><p style="font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18px; color:#545454; float:right; text-align:right">design|Ionescu Ionut<p>
</div><!--wraper -->
</div><!--footer -->



</body>
</html>
```

Thx for you time and help

P.S. Sorry for the earlier question

......................

This is for Michael

```
<?php 
$erori = '';
$nr_erori = 0;
$mesaj_trimis = "nu";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name_field = $_POST['nume'] ;
    $telephone_field = $_POST['telefon'] ;
    $email_field = $_POST['email'] ;
    $message = $_POST['mesaj'] ;

    if ($name_field == '') { $erori .= 'Campul "Nume" este obligatoriu.<br>'; $nr_erori++; }
    if ($telephone_field == '') { $erori .= 'Campul "Telefon" este obligatoriu.<br>'; $nr_erori++; }
    if ($message == '') { $erori .= 'Campul "Mesaj" este obligatoriu.<br>'; $nr_erori++; }

    if ($nr_erori == 0) {
        $body = "De la: ".$name_field."</br> Telefon: ".$telephone_field."</br> </br> E-Mail: ".$email_field."</br> </br> Mesaj:</br> ".$message;
        $sender = "ere@ere.ro"; 
        $catre = "ere1@ere.ro";

// BEGIN SWIFT CLASS
        require("swiftmail/Swift.php");
        require("swiftmail/Swift/Connection/SMTP.php");

        $smtp=new Swift_Connection_SMTP("localhost");
        $smtp->setUsername("ere@ere.ro");
        $smtp->setPassword("xxxx");
        $swift =& new Swift($smtp);

        $message =& new Swift_Message("Mesaj de la formularul de contact al site-ului"); 
        $message->attach(new Swift_Message_Part($body, "text/html"));

        if ($swift->send($message, $catre, new Swift_Address($sender, "Office Site"))) {
            $mesaj_trimis = "da";
        }
// END SWIFT CLASS
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Contact</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="container2">
<div class="cont">
<table width="495" height="475" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="278"><?php  if ($nr_erori > 0) {     echo '<div>'.$erori.'</div>'; }  if ($mesaj_trimis == "da") {   echo "<div>Mesajul dumneavoastra a fost trimis. Va multumim !   </div>"; } else { ?>     <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">     <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="1" />       <table width="278"  height="362"   border="0">         <tr>           <td width="150">*Nume</td>           <td width="340"><label>             <input type="text" name="nume" id="nume" />           </label></td>         </tr>         <tr>           <td>*Telefon</td>           <td><label>             <input type="text" name="telefon" id="telefon" />           </label></td>         </tr>         <tr>           <td>E-mail</td>           <td><label>             <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />           </label></td>         </tr>         <tr>           <td>*Mesajul Dumneavoastra</td>           <td><label>             <textarea name="mesaj" id="mesaj" cols="16" rows="10"></textarea>           </label></td>         </tr>         
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">! Campurile marcate cu * sunt OBLIGATORI</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>           <td>&nbsp;</td>           <td><label>             <input type="submit" name="submit_bt" id="submit_bt" value="Trimite" />           </label></td>         </tr>       </table>     </form> 
      <p>
        <?php } ?>
        <br />

      </p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <td width="207" height="471"><table width="203" height="383" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td height="379" valign="top"><p>Ambulanta Veterinara Mina Vet S.R.L.<br />
          <br />
          Str. Constantin Nottara, Nr.2, Sector 3 , Bucuresti </p>
          <table width="201" height="103" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td>Telefon:</td>
              <td>0726.223.374</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="23">&nbsp;</td>
              <td>0725.533.502</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Fax:</td>
              <td>0372.872.427</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="23">E-mail</td>
              <td>contact@minavet.ro</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <p></p></td>
      </tr>
      </table> 

    </table></div>
<div class="google">

<iframe width="400" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Strada+Constantin+C.+Nottara,+Bucharest,+Romania&amp;sll=44.420111,26.133664&amp;sspn=0.006774,0.01929&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Strada+Constantin+C.+Nottara,+Romania&amp;ll=44.424708,26.136389&amp;spn=0.021454,0.034332&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Strada+Constantin+C.+Nottara,+Bucharest,+Romania&amp;sll=44.420111,26.133664&amp;sspn=0.006774,0.01929&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Strada+Constantin+C.+Nottara,+Romania&amp;ll=44.424708,26.136389&amp;spn=0.021454,0.034332&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
</div>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters it might help if the $(".example7").colorbox() matched the class of the contact link. Just a guess, though.

If you don't want to debug this yourself, try stan-js (that IE7 behaviour compatibility thing).

Comment: thx mario but $(".example7").colorbox() is not in use here only shadowbox as you can see rel="shadowbox" on contact[at]termo-gaz-instal.ro

Answer (score 0):

there seems to have some misinterpretation of CSS in IE.

Try to set a white background in contact.php, it did the trick for some file of mine.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Really? Because I tested on some file of mine with shadowbox, I had the same problem of page loading but not displaying, by setting background to white in body of the page to open, it worked. Could you please put the code of contact.php so that we can have a better idea of what's not working ?

Comment: @John I tested the file you gave with setting background white for the body, it did the trick for me. Don't know what could be wrong with yours.